# Bootstrap dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrapping, HTML and everything that has to do with web development. I am building a dashboard using bootstrap and I managed to get the basic layout correct. My dashboard has a top and side navigation bar. [image]

I now want to navigate between the different pages without having to reload the side and top navigation bars. So I just want the center part of the page to load content whenever the links on the navigation bar are clicked and have the clicked links change background colour to indicate the user is currently on the respective page. This is my content div

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container" id="content">
     </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to Google some tutorials but I am battling to get the appropriate results because I think my search key words are kind of vague. Is there anywhere I can read to learn such stuff or is there anyone in here to help me out.

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="background:white">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Dijo_logo" src="https://dijoapp.co.za/dashboard_resources/logos/dijo8.png"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="dijoapp.co.za">Admin</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Statistics<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Ratings and Reviews</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="section">
            <div class="container" id="content">
              <div class="side-body"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: use bootstrap tab feature instead of navigation. It is exactly what you want . http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly answering your exact question, but will make it irrelevant,
it seems you are reinventing the wheel here.
Many before you created many templates for Admin Panels/Dashboards.

One of my favorite is [SB Admin < Link](http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/admin-dashboard/)

you can see some more templates on [this site](http://startbootstrap.com/)

Comment: I agree, unless you have a specific reason to be making your own, just use an existing one

Answer (score 0):

For the changing background-color part corresponding to which page is open, use the "active" class already described in the Bootstrap CSS.

`<li class="active">
  <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
</li>`

As you can see, the `<li>` containing Dashboard has been assigned the class "active". On each page corresponding to the links on the nav-bar, assign this "active" class to the respective `<li>` on the nav-bar, and remove it from the other `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are trying to achieve is a single page application.

You can create a dashboard with navigation that only changes the content area without reloading the page using JavaScript, jQuery, or AJAX.

Here is an article that can guide you through to create an SPA -(Single Page Application) [Create a Single Page App with jQuery](https://ilovecoding.org/lessons/ajax-create-a-single-page-app-with-jquery)

However, a much easier way to achieve this is to use a JavaScript framework like Angular.

If you are a beginner in Angular, This article can help you start with Bootstrap and Angular - [How to Use Bootstrap 4 with Angular](https://www.bootstrapdash.com/use-bootstrap-4-with-angular/)